# Duplicate entry in the macOS VPN menu in the menu bar

Tags: macos, vpn

I have some VPNs configured on my mac. When I add a new VPN, things look normal i.e. there is a new item in the VPN menu on the menu bar.

However, after I connect to at least one of these VPNs, a duplicate entry always appears. In the image below, notice there are two "Disconnect [my VPN]" items in the menu, but they refer to the same VPN, and if I click either, both turn into "Connect [my VPN]".

I'm running macOS Catalina, but it's been there since at least Mojave.

Does someone know some explanation for this unexpected behaviour? Is there a way to solve it?

[image: Screenshot of the menu bar]

Comment: It's a bug since macOS Catalina, and still not fixed in latest macOS Monterey

Answer (score 7):

I was able to temporarily remove the additional entry on Catalina by unclicking "Show VPN Status in Menu Bar", and re-enabling.

Will amend answer pending further research.

Comment: worked for me as well

Comment: For some reason I had to reconfigure my VPN so currently the problem is gone for me. I'll keep an eye and will try to remember to come back to this question with further info in case it didn't work (or mark it as the answer )

Comment: For me this seems to work. The duplicate entry has not reappeared, yet....

Comment: I stand corrected: it did reappear at some point... :-(

Comment: Same here. It will reappear at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by deleting the profile on the network settings and then restarting the menu bar with the below command.

```
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

- Rename the VPN
- Uncheck "Show VPN status in menu bar"
- Check it again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).